# Is there a switch-like keyword that would accept string (char *) instead of just char?

Tags: c

I hope that you already know that `switch` keyword only accepts `int` or `char`. but is there a way so that it would also accept `char *`?

I have an Idea how to solve this by using struct, but I'm gonna wait for your opinion.

Comment: There's no meaningful way you could make `char[]`/`char*` work with a switch statement. You would need to be able to provide compile time constants for the case statements to compare for equality, and you won't be able to provide that.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no, you cannot have string literals in `switch` statements. This is because switching a `char*` would mean the cases need to be memory addresses (after all, `char*` is still just a pointer).